# Color based on (discrete) derivative of function

Tags: graphics, animation, color

I am making a very basic stock simulation. I want `ListLinePlot` to color my stock viewer based on whether the price went up or down from the previous price. Here is what I have:

```
RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
price = 100;
time = 0;
nextPrice := price += 2Random[]-1;
nextTime := time += Random[];
data = Table[{nextTime, nextPrice},{i,1,1000}];
Dynamic@ListLinePlot[
    data,
    ImageSize->1000,
    PlotRange->{{time-525,time+25}},
    ColorFunction->Function[If[Last@data[[-2]]<Last@data[[-1]], Green, Red]]
]
RunScheduledTask[
    data = Rest[data];
    AppendTo[data,{nextTime,nextPrice}];,
    .1
];
```

Currently this code makes the graph all one color (not what I want). Does anyone know how to implement the functionality that I want? Also any general code improvements are very welcome (I feel like the way I am pushing/popping `data` is inefficient).

Comment: Have you looked at the various financial charting function such as `TradingChart` and `InteractiveTradingChart`? See the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InteractiveTradingChart.html?q=InteractiveTradingChart&lang=en). I can never bring myself to explore them further (just can't come up with any use for them), but they look close to what you want.

Comment: You seem to be generating a time series; you might want to look into `Accumulate[]`.

Comment: @Jens I saw those functions, but they seem limited to "dates", I am thinking more along the lines of "microseconds". @J.M. I don't want to use `Accumulate` because I don't want to store all the data at once. Or perhaps I am misunderstanding how you think I should use it?

Comment: Also, as long as I'm at it, any tips on how to make the graph less shaky looking?

Answer (score 2):

This small modification to your code

- Seems to flicker less than your code
- Doesn't make use of Scheduled Tasks
- Stops when you click on the plot

---

```
price = 100;
 time = 0;
nextPrice := price += 2 Random[] - 1;
nextTime := time += Random[];
data = Table[{nextTime, nextPrice}, {i, 1, 1000}];
lastPriceChecked = price;
lastTimeChecked = time;
colorFunction[x_, y_] := 
  If[x == First[First[data]], lastPriceChecked = y;
   Return[Blue], If[y > lastPriceChecked, lastPriceChecked = y;
     Return[Green], lastPriceChecked = y;
     Return[Red]];];
cont = True;
DynamicModule[{}, 
 EventHandler[
  Dynamic@ListLinePlot[data, ImageSize -> 1000, 
    PlotRange -> {{time - 525, time + 25}}, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, colorFunction[x, y]], 
    AxesOrigin -> {time - 525, 100}], "MouseDown" :> (cont = False)]]
While[cont, (Pause[.1]; data = Rest[data];
   AppendTo[data, {nextTime, nextPrice}])];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved my own question, though there is almost certainly a "more proper" way to do it. Please post if you have a better way than this.

```
RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
price = 100;
time = 0;
nextPrice := price += 2 Random[] - 1;
nextTime := time += Random[];
data = Table[{nextTime, nextPrice}, {i, 1, 1000}];
lastPriceChecked = price;
lastTimeChecked = time;
colorFunction[x_, y_] := If[
   x == First[First[data]],
   lastPriceChecked = y;
   Return[Blue],
   If[
     y > lastPriceChecked,
     lastPriceChecked = y;
     Return[Green],
     lastPriceChecked = y;
     Return[Red]
     ];
   ];
Dynamic@ListLinePlot[data, ImageSize -> 1000, 
  PlotRange -> {{time - 525, time + 25}}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, colorFunction[x, y]]]
RunScheduledTask[
  data = Rest[data];
  AppendTo[data, {nextTime, nextPrice}];
  , .1];
```